# How to Change Magento 2 Product Tab

Tags: magento2

Hi currently Magento 2 provide default tab in Product View Page. Now i want to add or change to custom product tab in view page.

Any one have idea how to change custom tab in magento 2.

Comment: might be this link will be useful @ http://www.woolleydesign.net/2016/03/magento-2-add-custom-tab-to-product-page/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify product tabs from catalog_product_view.xml in your theme or module.

If you want to remove a tab : (description here)

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.description" remove="true" />
```

If you want to add a new one :

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="example.tab" as="example"
                   template="Example_Module::example.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Example</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

The same way you can modify existing one.